# кодек ascii не может кодировать символы

Tags: python, smtplib

Перепробовал многое, но не могу разобраться с ошибкой. Видел кучу решений, но всё не то

```
import smtplib


def send_email(message):
    sender = 'MAIL'
    password = 'PASSWORD'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()

    try:
        server.login(sender, password)
        msg = message
        server.sendmail(sender, sender, msg)
        return "The message was sent successfully!"
    except Exception as _ex:
        return f"{_ex}\nCheck your login or password please!"


def main():
    message = input("Type your message: ")
    print(send_email(message=message))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\newFolderForPyChProjects\mail.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\newFolderForPyChProjects\mail.py", line 24, in main
    print(send_email(message=message))
  File "E:\newFolderForPyChProjects\mail.py", line 10, in send_email
    server.ehlo()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 446, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 373, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 357, in send
    s = s.encode(self.command_encoding)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Имя компьютера на русском языке небось?

Comment: Отвечаю через аккаунт друга, проблма была в названии пк

Answer (score 0):

Декодируйте из **utf-8** с игнорированием символов, потом закодируйте в **asci**, если Вам Эту кодировку надо. Ну или укажите, которую надо:

```
your_message = message.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```